# Sql server for-each,or while row

Tags: sql-server, loops, t-sql

First I Used AdvantureWork2019 DB you can use it to see the same result that I have, if you want to test it and I'll add a script to Create The Discount Tables at the end and to create the view I used to create the ##tempTables, My question is:

I have 2 Temp tables the first one is This:

```
DiscID  Desc    DiscLimitID Limit         DiscPercID    Perc    Qty      DiscQtyID  Allowed Allocated
1        NA         1       0.0000000         1      0.0200000  1.0000000   1      0.0000000    0.0000000
2        Cheap      2       50.0000000        2      0.0100000  4.0000000   2   1000.0000000    0.0000000
3        Moderate   3       200.0000000       3      0.0250000  3.0000000   3   5000.0000000    0.0000000
4        Expensive  4       1000.0000000      4      0.0500000  2.0000000   4   20000.0000000   5000.0000000
```

The second one :

```
SalesOrderID    SalesOrderDetailID  LineTotal   OrderQty    ODiscID
43659                   1          2024.994000      1         0
43659                   2          6074.982000      3         4
43659                   3          2024.994000      1         0
43659                   4          2039.994000      1         0
43659                   5          2039.994000      1         0
43659                   6          4079.988000      2         4
43659                   7          2039.994000      1         0
43659                   8          86.521200        3         0
43659                   9          28.840400        1         1
43659                  10          34.200000        6         1
```

I made a query to give me this result (sample) :

```
SOdID   LineTotal   DiscID  Discount    FinalTotal  FinalAllocated
9   28.840400   1   0.576808    28.263592   0.576808
10  34.200000   1   0.684000    33.516000   1.260808
11  10.373000   1   0.207460    10.165540   1.468268
18  20.746000   1   0.414920    20.331080   1.883188
12  80.746000   2   0.807460    79.938540   0.807460
19  115.361600  2   1.153616    114.207984  1.961076
29  100.932500  2   1.009325    99.923175   2.970401
85  173.042400  2   1.730424    171.311976  4.700825
105 115.361600  2   1.153616    114.207984  5.854441
139 80.746000   2   0.807460    79.938540   6.661901
34  551.814600  3   13.795365   538.019235  13.795365
44  535.742400  3   13.393560   522.348840  27.188925
95  551.814600  3   13.795365   538.019235  40.984290
104 535.742400  3   13.393560   522.348840  54.377850
2   6074.982000 4   303.749100  5771.232900 303.749100
6   4079.988000 4   203.999400  3875.988600 507.748500
17  1429.408600 4   71.470430   1357.938170 579.218930
20  1445.189800 4   72.259490   1372.930310 651.478420
21  6074.982000 4   303.749100  5771.232900 955.227520
22  4049.988000 4   202.499400  3847.488600 1157.726920
24  1637.400000 4   81.870000   1555.530000 1239.596920
```

what I want to do now is to make a Cursor or While loop to stop the query from making `Discount` and adding to the `FinalAllocated` and replace it to 0

for Example if `DiscID` = 3 reached 5000(`FinalAllocated`) then stop the query from continue for `DiscID` 3 and Add 0 `Discount` to the rest of the Rows which contain `DiscID = 3` then go to the next `DiscID` which is 4 and start again

Ex:

```
while (FinalAllocated < Allowed for that ID)
Contnue
Else 0
```

Here you'll find everything I used to test it if you like

From AdventureWork2019 DB:

```
    Create View vSalesOrderAll As
  select SOH.SalesOrderID,SOD.SalesOrderDetailID,SOD.LineTotal,SOH.OrderDate,SOD.OrderQty from sales.SalesOrderDetail as SOD
  Inner Join [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] AS SOH ON 
  SOD.SalesOrderID = SOH.SalesOrderID
```

Script for Discount Tables :

```
USE [AdventureWorks2019]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[DiscountClass]    Script Date: 6/29/2020 12:29:43 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DiscountClass](
    [DiscountClassID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DiscountClass] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DiscountClassID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[DiscountLimit]    Script Date: 6/29/2020 12:29:43 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DiscountLimit](
    [DiscountLimitID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DiscountClassID] [int] NULL,
    [Limit] [numeric](24, 7) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DiscountLimit] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DiscountLimitID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[DiscountPercentage]    Script Date: 6/29/2020 12:29:43 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DiscountPercentage](
    [DiscountPercentageID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DiscountLimitID] [int] NULL,
    [Quantity] [numeric](24, 7) NULL,
    [Percentage] [numeric](24, 7) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DiscountPercentage] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DiscountPercentageID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[DiscountQuota]    Script Date: 6/29/2020 12:29:43 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DiscountQuota](
    [DiscountQuotaId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DiscountClassId] [int] NULL,
    [Allowed] [numeric](24, 7) NULL,
    [Allocated] [numeric](24, 7) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DiscountQuota] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DiscountQuotaId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[DiscountClass] ON 

INSERT [dbo].[DiscountClass] ([DiscountClassID], [Description]) VALUES (1, N'NA')
INSERT [dbo].[DiscountClass] ([DiscountClassID], [Description]) VALUES (2, N'Cheap')
INSERT [dbo].[DiscountClass] ([DiscountClassID], [Description]) VALUES (3, N'Moderate')
INSERT [dbo].[DiscountClass] ([DiscountClassID], [Description]) VALUES (4, N'Expensive')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[DiscountClass] OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[DiscountLimit] ON 

INSERT [dbo].[DiscountLimit] ([DiscountLimitID], [DiscountClassID], [Limit]) VALUES (1, 1, CAST(0.0000000 AS Numeric(24, 7)))
INSERT [dbo].[DiscountLimit] ([DiscountLimitID], [DiscountClassID], [Limit]) VALUES (2, 2, CAST(50.0000000 AS Numeric(24, 7)))
INSERT [dbo].[DiscountLimit] ([DiscountLimitID], [DiscountClassID], [Limit]) VALUES (3, 3, CAST(200.0000000 AS Numeric(24, 7)))
INSERT [dbo].[DiscountLimit] ([DiscountLimitID], [DiscountClassID], [Limit]) VALUES (4, 4, CAST(1000.0000000 AS Numeric(24, 7)))
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[DiscountLimit] OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[DiscountPercentage] ON 

INSERT [dbo].[DiscountPercentage] ([DiscountPercentageID], [DiscountLimitID], [Quantity], [Percentage]) VALUES (1, 1, CAST(1.0000000 AS Numeric(24, 7)), CAST(0.0200000 AS Numeric(24, 7)))
INSERT [dbo].[DiscountPercentage] ([DiscountPercentageID], [DiscountLimitID], [Quantity], [Percentage]) VALUES (2, 2, CAST(4.0000000 AS Numeric(24, 7)), CAST(0.0100000 AS Numeric(24, 7)))
INSERT [dbo].[DiscountPercentage] ([DiscountPercentageID], [DiscountLimitID], [Quantity], [Percentage]) VALUES (3, 3, CAST(3.0000000 AS Numeric(24, 7)), CAST(0.0250000 AS Numeric(24, 7)))
INSERT [dbo].[DiscountPercentage] ([DiscountPercentageID], [DiscountLimitID], [Quantity], [Percentage]) VALUES (4, 4, CAST(2.0000000 AS Numeric(24, 7)), CAST(0.0500000 AS Numeric(24, 7)))
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[DiscountPercentage] OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[DiscountQuota] ON 

INSERT [dbo].[DiscountQuota] ([DiscountQuotaId], [DiscountClassId], [Allowed], [Allocated]) VALUES (1, 1, CAST(0.0000000 AS Numeric(24, 7)), CAST(0.0000000 AS Numeric(24, 7)))
INSERT [dbo].[DiscountQuota] ([DiscountQuotaId], [DiscountClassId], [Allowed], [Allocated]) VALUES (2, 2, CAST(10000.0000000 AS Numeric(24, 7)), CAST(0.0000000 AS Numeric(24, 7)))
INSERT [dbo].[DiscountQuota] ([DiscountQuotaId], [DiscountClassId], [Allowed], [Allocated]) VALUES (3, 3, CAST(50000.0000000 AS Numeric(24, 7)), CAST(0.0000000 AS Numeric(24, 7)))
INSERT [dbo].[DiscountQuota] ([DiscountQuotaId], [DiscountClassId], [Allowed], [Allocated]) VALUES (4, 4, CAST(200000.0000000 AS Numeric(24, 7)), CAST(5000.0000000 AS Numeric(24, 7)))
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[DiscountQuota] OFF
GO
```

Second View :

```
   Create View vAllDiscounts As
   select DS.DiscountClassID,DS.Description
   ,DL.DiscountLimitID,DL.Limit
   ,DP.DiscountPercentageID,DP.Percentage,DP.Quantity
   ,DQ.DiscountQuotaId,DQ.Allowed,DQ.Allocated
   from DiscountClass DS Inner join
  DiscountLimit DL ON  DS.DiscountClassID = DL.DiscountClassID
  INNER JOIN DiscountPercentage DP ON DL.DiscountLimitID = DP.DiscountLimitID
  INNER JOIN DiscountQuota DQ ON DQ.DiscountClassId = DL.DiscountClassID
```

Temp Tables :

```
select *
INTO ##TempDiscount
from vAllDiscounts 


select *
INTO ##TempOrederData
from vSalesOrderAll
```

The ODiscId

```
update TOD
SET TOD.ODiscID = (CASE WHEN TOD.LineTotal <= 49 AND TOD.OrderQty >= 1  THEN 1
            WHEN TOD.LineTotal >= 50 AND TOD.LineTotal <= 199 AND TOD.OrderQty >= 4 THEN 2
            WHEN TOD.LineTotal >= 200 AND TOD.LineTotal <= 999 AND TOD.OrderQty >= 3 THEN 3
            WHEN TOD.LineTotal >= 1000 AND TOD.OrderQty >= 2 THEN  4
            ELSE 0 END)
from ##TempOrederData AS TOD
```

This is the query that I've used to get my output:

```
WITH TotalDisc AS
(
SELECT TOD.SalesOrderID,TOD.SalesOrderDetailID AS SOdID
,TOD.LineTotal,TOD.OrderQty,TOD.OrderDate,AD.DiscountClassID AS DiscID 
,Percentage ,(LineTotal*Percentage) AS Discount, AD.Allocated,AD.Allowed AS Allo

FROM ##TempOrederData TOD
INNER JOIN ##TempDiscount AD ON TOD.ODiscID = AD.DiscountClassID 
), TotalAndDiscount AS
(
SELECT SalesOrderID,SOdID,LineTotal,OrderQty,OrderDate,DiscID,Discount,Allocated,LineTotal-Discount AS FinalTotal
FROM TotalDisc
)
SELECT SOdID,LineTotal,DiscID,Discount,FinalTotal,
sum(Discount) over ( Partition by DiscID order by SOdID) AS FinalAllocated
FROM TotalAndDiscount
```

EDIT :
I Added the Case Statement to stop it when it reach a limit

```
WITH TotalDisc AS
(
SELECT TOD.SalesOrderID,TOD.SalesOrderDetailID AS SOdID
,TOD.LineTotal,TOD.OrderQty,TOD.OrderDate,AD.DiscountClassID AS DiscID 
,Percentage ,(LineTotal*Percentage) AS Discount, AD.Allocated AS Allc,AD.Allowed AS Allo

FROM ##TempOrederData TOD
INNER JOIN ##TempDiscount AD ON TOD.ODiscID = AD.DiscountClassID 
), TotalAndDiscount AS
(
SELECT SalesOrderID,SOdID,LineTotal,OrderQty,OrderDate,DiscID,Discount,Allc,LineTotal-Discount AS FinalTotal
FROM TotalDisc
), FinalCalc AS
(
SELECT SOdID,LineTotal,DiscID,Discount,FinalTotal,
sum(Discount) over ( Partition by DiscID order by SOdID) AS FinalAllocated
FROM TotalAndDiscount
),TestAllo AS
(
Select *
,Allocated = SUM(CASE   WHEN DiscID = 1 AND FinalAllocated < 5000 THEN  FinalAllocated
                        WHEN DiscID = 2 AND FinalAllocated < 10000 THEN  FinalAllocated
                        WHEN DiscID = 3 AND FinalAllocated < 20000 THEN  FinalAllocated
                        WHEN DiscID = 4 AND FinalAllocated < 50000 THEN  FinalAllocated
                        Else '0' END ) 
from FinalCalc
group by FinalCalc.SodID,FinalCalc.LineTotal,FinalCalc.DiscID,FinalCalc.Discount,FinalCalc.FinalTotal,FinalCalc.FinalAllocated
)
select * from TestAllo
where Allocated != 0
order by DiscID
```

Edit 2 :

Desired Output would be something like that

```
SOdID   LineTotal   DiscID  Discount    FinalTotal  FinalAllocated  Allocated
    915 2144.112900     4   107.205645  2036.907255 48226.798765    48226.798765
    916 27055.760424    4   1352.788021 25702.972403    49579.586786    49579.586786
    918 8159.976000     4   407.998800  7751.977200 49987.585586    49987.585586
    924 1749.588000     4   0           1749.588000 49987.585586    0.000000
    928 1749.588000     4   0           1749.588000 49987.585586    0.000000
    932 1749.588000     4   0           1749.588000 49987.585586    0.000000
    934 2097.294500     4   0           2097.294500 49987.585586    0.000000
    942 1258.376700     4   0           1258.376700 49987.585586    0.000000
```

is when Allocated reach the limit I want it to stop the discount and replace the next Discounts with 0 and to take The allowed from the discount table which would be something like that :

```
CASE    WHEN DiscID = 1 AND FinalAllocated < (Select allowed from DiscountQuota where DiscId=1) THEN  FinalAllocated
```

but I keep getting this error

```
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.
```

Again what i'm trying to achieve is to make a Cursor or While statement to stop the sum when the (FinalAllocated) > Allowed for that ID from table ##TempDiscount

Thank you in Advance

Comment: The non cursor loop way to do this is called "Cumulative Sum" and can be found [here](https://codingsight.com/calculating-running-total-with-over-clause-and-partition-by-clause-in-sql-server/). If you really want to do it in a loop then search for "sql server cursor"

Comment: I've already did that, you can see that in my query, what I'm trying to do now is to stop it when it reach a specified number and replacing the discount to 0 (after reaching the specified allowed)

Comment: I am not exactly sure what exactly your problem is. I think you need to do add a `CASE WHEN` expression to check for your condition e.g. `CASE WHEN ( SUM( Discount ) OVER .... ) >= Allocated THEN 0 ELSE  SUM( Discount ) OVER .... END`

Comment: If this does not help you please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). (It is very good that you have taken the time to post all the code (DDL and DML) to re-create your problem but it is quite a lot to process).

Comment: I solved half of the problem by using Case Statemnt i'll add an Edit, my only problem now is to make this work somehow
`WHEN DiscID = 1 AND FinalAllocated < Allowed for ID=1 THEN  FinalAllocated`

Comment: Why are you hard-coding IDs? You have `DiscountQuota` table with all of the values, just join onto it based on IDs.

Comment: I know my way of doing it, is ugly but I tried multiple times doing multiple different things but none worked that's why i'm doing this right now

Comment: Do one small step at a time and check results i.e. start simple and keep adding complexity small step at a time. Commenting your code can help you here as well, as it helps to define what each step (or CTE) is trying to achieve.

Comment: In your updated query I do not understand the purpose of  `group by`.

Comment: I had to because I used the `SUM()`

Comment: Why do you need to use SUM if you are not actually aggregating?

Comment: because i'm using `FinalAllocated` from the `With` before  you can take a look here on the results  [Here][1]

  [1]: https://ibb.co/TM1NDpV

Comment: I am confused about what you are trying to achieve. The "regular" group by produces a different result to a Cumulative Sum window function that you have used before. Perhaps you should include desired results in your question.

Comment: When DiscID = 1 reaches the limit, DiscID =2 is starting from that value (say 4998.75) or from 0? Does it have to be one query?

Comment: it start again from 0 you can find it in the query, and no it doesn't have to be one query I just want the best solution that it work then i'll keep fixing it to give me better process time and faster result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the output fields in the temp tables to help with the calculations.

First calculate the `FinalAllocated` without any restrictions:

```
WITH FinalAllocatedCTE AS (
  SELECT
      SalesOrderID
    , FinalAllocated
    , SUM(Discount) OVER (PARTITION BY DiscID ORDER BY LineTotal ASC) AS Calc_FinalAllocated
  FROM
    ##TempOrederData
)
UPDATE
  FinalAllocatedCTE
SET
  FinalAllocated = Calc_FinalAllocated
```

Then reset the records which are over the limits:

```
UPDATE
  DST
SET
  FinalAllocated= 0
FROM
  ##TempOrederData AS DST
  INNER JOIN ##TempDiscount AS DISC
    ON     DST.DiscID = DISC.DiscID
       AND DST.FinalAllocated > DISC.Limit
;
```

Now you can do whatever you want with the records having 0 in FinalAllocated:

```
DECLARE @MaxAllocated TABLE (DiscID INT, MaxAllocated DECIMAL...);

INSERT INTO MaxAllocated (DiscID, MaxAllocated)
SELECT DiscID, MAX(FinalAllocated) AS MaxAllocated FROM ##TempOrederData
;

UPDATE
  DST
SET 
    DST.FinalAllocated= MA.MaxAllocated
  , DST.Discount = 0
  , DST.Allocated = 0
FROM
  ##TempOrederData AS DST
  INNER JOIN @MaxAllocated AS MA
    ON DST.DiscID = MA.DiscID
WHERE
  TotalAllocated = 0
;
```

Comment: you are da man, I changed the query and then applied your solution and it worked like a charm, Thank you very much

Comment: welcome. For the future: when you start to lose track of your own solution, try to break it down into smaller steps, deal with only one problem at once and solve it, don't try to solve everything in one step. You can always go back and merge or optimize already existing parts of the solution

Comment: Is it `SUM()` or `SUM() OVER ()`? If you just want to calculate the Discount for each row, you don't need SUM, if you want to calculate the rolling sum, you want `SUM() OVER()` and you don't need group by, if you want to get the SUM of all discounts, you want to do it in a different query.